# How to translate offline and keep the format of document?

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I used the [document translation API from google](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=docs&sl=pt&tl=en). And also I could use [Google-trans Python](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/).

However, I could not figure out a way to:

1. Translate document
2. KEEP a high percentage of original format, such as [Google Translate Toolkit](https://translate.google.com/toolkit/list?hl=en#translations/active) does.

Have you experienced or have a suggestion to translate a document offline and keep the format of the document?

Comment: See this:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hPH7skySCZR-ZMJ6TmYLN1ug6vbq2cpb

Comment: And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425218/offline-language-translation-api